# How can I tell htaccess that URLs with slashes are not directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, content-management-system

I have a custom micro-CMS made in PHP. It uses friendly-URLs, so I have a htaccess which is based on that of Drupal, it directs all pages to index.php. Now I have a problem, if I have a page of this kind:

```
www.example.com/products/brandA/prices
```

all the images, css, etc., are broken, presumably because Apache thinks that the path of the images, which is relative, has the reference of /products/brandA/prices, as if they were directories.

I can solve it by putting <base href="http://www.example.com/"> but Drupal does not use it and works perfectly. Is there some elegant solution? Why is this happening? What htaccess would be the most adequate for my purposes? ( all URLs which are not archives should go through index.php, and friendly-URLs should be accepted ).

Comment: Where are your css and js located? (path/to/css)

Comment: Why not set your asset paths with root and declare "RewriteBase / " in your htaccess? Have you tried that? <img src="/images/myimg.jpg" /> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />

Comment: With /images/myimg.jpg works. I see RewriteBase / is also put. That must be a winner config. Thanks!